# php mysql select with array in to array

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to select ids from database with arrays.
my english not good. I  think the best way to show my codes

the form result `print_r($malayalam);` like this `Array ( [0] => helo [1] => hi[2] => how)`

I need to select its ids from table. my code is not correct. any way let me show you here

```
$results=mysql_query("SELECT ml_id FROM ml_table WHERE word = '$malayalam'"); 
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($results);
if($numrows!=0){
    $ml_row = mysql_fetch_array($results);
    $ml_id = $ml_row['ml_id'] ;
    echo "Malayalam ID " . $ml_id . "<br />";
}
```

I need to add all my result in to another array.

is that possible ?
if u have any idea could you answer to me please

Comment: What does the table data look like? What are the names of the columns? I don't think the $malayalam array is going to work in the SQL SELECT statement the way you want it to either.

Comment: @sbohan Hi 
table name is ml_table columns are ml_id, word 

the thing is that I need to select ml_id from thable which are equal to `Array ( [0] => helo [1] => hi[2] => how)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally fainally found solution with the help of answers

```
$rArray = mysql_query("SELECT ml_id FROM ml_table WHERE word IN ('".implode("', '", $malayalam)."')"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($rArray)>0){
    $temp_rows = array();       
    while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($rArray))) {
        $temp_rows[] = $row['ml_id'];
    }
}
```

the result of `print_r($temp_rows)` coming like this `Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => 234 [2] => 312)`

thank to all

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0;       
foreach($malayalam as $key=>$value)
{
    $results=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ml_table WHERE word = '$value'"); 
    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($results);
    if($numrows!=0)
    {
         $ml_row = mysql_fetch_array($results);
         $ml_id = $ml_row['ml_id'] ;
         $ml_ad[$i]=$ml_id;
         echo "Malayalam ID " . $ml_id . "<br />";
         $i++;
     }
 }
```

Now when you `printr($ml_ad);` it will show all your id's in an array.

Comment: I need to all selected `ml_id` in to $ml_ad as a array

Answer (score 0):

If I understood properly, the following is what you need

```
$results=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ml_table WHERE word = '$malayalam'"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($results)>0){

    $newArray = array(); //Create a new array

    while($ml_row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        $ml_id = $ml_row['ml_id'] ;
        $newArray[$ml_id] = $ml_row;
        echo "Malayalam ID " . $ml_id . "<br />";
    }

    //$newArray is your new array accesible from id

}
```

Comment: Try to run the command, alone using phpmyadmin only and see if outputs anything.

Comment: I think the problem on $malayalam.  bcos it is also array.

Comment: @maanu, of course, thats a problem. It is not designed to read an array.

Comment: do u know how to select with array ?

Comment: There might be a way to do so, but i need to know, what kind of array it is? and what sort of comparison you need?

Comment: actually it is for a form i can show you the link http://www.chatfitness.com/add_english.php. I need to add new words. this function for checking that this word already exist in the table

Comment: @maanu, So then why do you need to pass it as an array. Pass it as a single word, instead of any array. Extract it using something like `$arr[0]` and pass it to the query.

Comment: I need to collect all `ml_id` to use another function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8487/discussion-between-maanu-and-starx)

Comment: I am so sorry. It was already 1 o clock at night, had to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

You should write something like this:

```
$ids = array();
$in = '"' . implode('","', array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $malayalam)) . '"';
$result = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM ml_table WHERE word IN(' . $in . ')');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $ids[] = $row['id'];
}

$anotherArray = array_merge($ids, $anotherArray);
OR
$anotherArray += $ids;
```